# Blank pages in PDF retrieved from API

Tags: node.js, pdf, meteor, encoding, fs

My web application is making a HTTPS GET request to an external API. What I receive is a PDF file that starts with:

```
%PDF-1.4
```

What I would like to do is save this PDF on the server to serve this file to the client. The problem is that there are some blank pages in the PDF where there should be none.

Here is the code responsible for retrieving the PDF and saving it to the server:

```
    Meteor.http.get('url/' + chartId,  {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + key.token
      }
    }, function(err, result) {
      if(!err) {
        var fs = Npm.require('fs');
        var path = process.env['METEOR_SHELL_DIR'] + '/../../../public';

        fs.writeFile(path + "/charts/" + Meteor.userId() + '.pdf', result.content, (function (err) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("Error:" + err);
          }
        }));

      } else {
        throw new Error('Error from API getting documents');
      }
    });
```

The weird thing is that the PDF I save to the server shows pages with text on them, but shows blank pages where there should be images (charts). Perhabs this is an encoding issue?

Comment: Is it possible that `result.content` returns the content as a string of characters? In that case you would have to look for a different property which returns it as the original bytes.

Comment: @mkl `result.content` indeed returns a string of characters. Unfortunately this is the only data I can get from the response. Is there a way to get the original bytes from this string?

Comment: Interpreting a binary file as text usually is destructive, i.e. non-reversible. As I'm not that knowledgeable concerning Javascript and in particular Meteor, I don't know whether the case at hand is an exception.

Comment: @mkl I think I found the problem. If I download the original and correct pdf and open it in a text editor (Atom) and save it. It results in a blank page. I think that the same thing happens when I try to get the HTTPS content result and save it to a file or send it to the client. Would you know any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as I first guessed this has something to do with encoding.
Make sure you set the right headers on the http request `encoding: 'binary'` and use the correct encoding while using .writeFile().

Source: [Node express save pdf from binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486379/node-express-save-pdf-from-binary-string)